# SQL copy table values to new table

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

Hello I am trying to copy the values which is in excel sheet to new table in same database using `Select * INTO query`.

The data which is extracted to excel is from other table and after editing some columns in excel, I need the excel sheet to be sent back to SQL database with new table creation.

I got problem with my code which says error :

```
Run- time error '-2147217900 ' Automation Error
```

I am using *VBA Macros* to import and export the table values to *SQL from Excel*.

Here is my Code

```
Dim adoCN As ADODB.Connection
Dim sConnString As String
Dim sSQL As String
Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long

sConnString = "Provider=sqloledb;Server=;Database=mycon;User Id=;Password="

Set adoCN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

adoCN.Open sConnString

'Assumes that you have Field1, Field2 and Field3 in columns A, B and C
'For this example we can assume that the data exists on Sheet1, with a header on row
'1 and data in rows 2-11
'Also assume that the fields are defined as character (e.g. varchar or char)
'Text values must be enclosed in apostrophes whereas numeric values should not.

'adoCN.Open

For lRow = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

sSQL = "SELECT * INTO TestTable FROM Sheets(1)$"

***adoCN.Execute sSQL***

Next lRow

adoCN.Close

Set adoCN = Nothing


'On Error GoTo 0
```

Error at Line : ***adoCN.Execute sSQL***

Please help me out.

Comment: can anybdy look into this question plz....

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Does your `TestTable` exist? and is your sheet really named `Sheets(1)`? or did you wish to use the worksheet object like `FROM " & Sheets(1).name & "$"` ? Also why are you using late-binding to create an adodb connection object? You can say `Set adoCN = new ADODB.Connection`

Comment: Is TestTable already exist in the database? SELECT INTO will try to create a new table each time it runs. If TestTable exists the statement will fail.

Comment: @ aaron im using excel 2007

Comment: yeah it does exist... im taking the sheet from excel so its named Sheets(1)$

Comment: @steve tried evn that... not working

Answer (score 1):

I am quite sure that the error is SQL not recognicing "Sheets(1)$". the Phrase i "sSQL" is sent into the adodb.connection, so it is not processed in Excel (although called from Excel-VBA). So any references from Excel would have to be passed there as a string already, otherwise they will lead to an error.

I would not try to put the whole table into SQL at once, but do this line for line, because if you have any data-problem (string to Long, wrong data-format) the whole table will be thrown back.

I would make it similiar to http://www.vb-magazin.de/forums/forums/post/9581.aspx

(if you need any help translating this let me know)

...with one IMPORTANT difference: After each "add.new" was sucessful, I would put a remark in the appropiate line in Excel, so it will for sure not be transported a second time. Do to this you would put after dbRecord.Update the line

```
xls_Appl.ActiveCell.Offset(I,6).Value = "send_to_sql"
```

Of course at the start of each line befor processing it you would want to check if this text is there already and if this is the case go to the next item.

I hope this helps you,
Max

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you can't do this.

**First: SELECT * INTO TestTable**

You can run this statement only one time. And you are trying to create the same table for each row in your spreadsheet.

**Second: .. FROM Sheets(1)$**

I'm not confident with VBA, but I suppose that you expecting something magical from ADO.NET.

You need to:

1. CREATE TABLE outside of FOR
2. INSERT INTO inside of FOR

Answer (score 0):

I can see some problems with that code.

First, you can't pass only the name of your sheet through an SQL statement. The SQL Server doesn't even know the existence of your sheet (or Excel at all, for that matter). They're completely separate instances.

Second, as someone already pointed out, every time you run `"SELECT * INTO ..."` statement you're actually creating a new table with only one row.

You should do something like this. I'm assuming (as you told in your comment) that `TestTable` already exists in the database, and that your sheet really is `Sheets(1)`. Also, you haven't told which column has which format, so I assumed they were all strings and put quotes around the values in the statement.

```
Dim adoCN As ADODB.Connection
Dim sConnString As String
Dim sSQL As String
Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long

sConnString = "Provider=sqloledb;Server=;Database=mycon;User Id=;Password="

Set adoCN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

adoCN.Open sConnString

With Sheets(1)

For lRow = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

  sSQL = "INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES ('" & .Cells(lRow, 1) & "', '" & .Cells(lRow, 2) & "', '" & .Cells(lRow, 3) & "')"

  adoCN.Execute sSQL

Next lRow

End With

adoCN.Close

Set adoCN = Nothing
```